# Empty item added in Wordpress carousel

Tags: wordpress, carousel

After a lot of research, I have no found a solution to this problem.

I have migrated my html site to a Wordpress theme, but after doing that I found a problem with carousel. On my html code it works perfectly, but on Wordpress it adds empty items to the carousel. 
Please any solution to this problem? 
I found a related question, but no ones responded it: 
[Wordpress owl carousel add empty item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47483893/wordpress-owl-carousel-add-empty-item)

Please!!

Here's a referencial image [image]

My code where I call the carousel

```
    <div class="gallery full-width side-arrow">
<div class="item">
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/sector/c_ba00.png" alt="">
</div>
<div class="item">
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/sector/c_ba.png" alt="">
</div>
 <div class="item">
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/sector/c_ba2.png" alt="">
</div>
<div class="item">
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/sector/c_ba3.png" alt="">
</div>
<div class="item">
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/sector/c_ba4.png" alt="">
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: hi,

can you give us a link to see it ? 
And can you give alt attribute a value for each image ?  did you check that you're 5 images are in the good folder, and the filename in the same case (lowercase) you call your images in your code ?

thanks

Comment: @Aurel this is the link: maradentro.com.bo

And the code above is the front-page.php where the html code is set up. All my images are in the right folder, which is the one I am calling at <img src=>
What do you mean with (lowercase)?
Thank you for reply

Comment: Thanks, as i see, you got 4 images and they are all displayed. no empty item after. Just the carousel doesn't take full width.
Where is your javascript owlCarousel init ?
Thanks